# XPath to check if a value exists in a element in java script

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to check whether values S1 or S2 exists in the below xml document using Xpath.
I have tried something like below , but its not working. Can anyone help me in this.?

I just need to know if any of the value ( S1 or S2)  exists.

```
Xpath I tried : "//Field/Array[String=S1 or String=S2]" 

XML Document :
     <Field name="F1">
        <Array name="A1">
          <String>S1</String>
          <String>S2</String>
          <String>S3</String>
          <String>S4</String>
        </Array>
      </Field>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use single or double quotes to indicate a string literal, otherwise it will be read as child element name instead :

```
//Field/Array[String='S1' or String='S2']
```

As posted your XPath will check if value of a `String` element equals to value of `S1` or `S2` element which will be evaluated to false since there is no child element named `S1` or `S2`.